# Trying to swap even/odd rows in a matrix (Java)

Tags: java, matrix

I'm trying to swap even and odd row indices in a matrix, so that all the even rows are at the top, and all the odd rows are at the bottom. I created the matrix beforehand.

Here's my code for the row swapping:

```
    int numberOfEvenRowIndices = 0;
    if(matrix.length%2.0 == 0){
        numberOfEvenRowIndices = matrix.length/2 - 1;
    }
    else{
        numberOfEvenRowIndices = (int) (matrix.length/2.0 - 0.5);
    }
    for(int m = 0; m < numberOfEvenRowIndices; m++){
         for (int k = 2; k < rows; k++){
            if((matrix[k][0]/10)%2 == 0.0){
                int firstEvenRow = k;

                for (int i = 0; i < matrix[firstEvenRow].length; i++){
                    //store value of first even row index
                    int temp = matrix[firstEvenRow][i];
                    //swap value of first even row with first odd row
                    matrix[firstEvenRow][i] = matrix[k-1][i];
                    matrix[k-1][i] = temp;}
        }
    }

   for( int i = 0 ; i < rows ; i++){
        for( int j = 0 ; j < columns ; j++){
            System.out.printf("%4s", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

And it outputs:

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7

40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47

20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27

60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67

10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17

30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37

50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57

70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77
```

I need the rows to go in order (top-bottom: 0, 20, 40, 60, 10, 30, 50, 70)
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Should there be suborder ASC/DESC as well? What i mean should odd and even be sorted relative to eachother ?

Comment: the original matrix is (top to bottom) 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60... and so on

Comment: and i need all the even rows pushed up so the first column looks like (top to bottom) 0, 20, 40, 60, 10, 30, 50

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution using `List`

```
    ArrayList<Integer[]> result = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
    ArrayList<Integer[]> odd = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();

    for (int i = 0, s = matrix.length; i < s; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 2) {
            result.add(matrix[i]);
        } else {
            odd.add(matrix[i]);
        }
    }
    result.addAll(odd);
    Integer[][] resultMatrix = result.toArray(new Integer[result.size()][]);
```

at the end you will have "sorted" matrix as 2d array.

Answer (score 0):

I would not pick a clever algorithm, but go for something readable:

```
void evenodd(int[][] matrix) {

    // New rows:
    int[] rows = new int[matrix.length];
    int rowI = 0;

    // Even rows:
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i += 2) {
        rows[rowI] = matrix[i];
        ++rowI;
    }

    // Odd rows:
    for (int i = 1; i < matrix.length; i += 2) {
        rows[rowI] = matrix[i];
        ++rowI;
    }
    System.arraycopy(rows, 0, matrix, 0, matrix.length);
}
```

Also do not use doubles but use integer division when needed:

```
int evenRows = (matrix.length + 1) / 2;
int oddRows = matrix.length / 2;
```

And of course swap entire rows.

Also the class Arrays had copyOf methods and such that might come in handy.